# shouldAutorotate -> false, still simulator rotates

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, autorotate, shouldautorotate

I'm making an app which supports landscape orientations only when playing a video. Otherwise, all the scenes support only portrait orientation. I've checked portrait, landscape left and right in project settings. I've written the following code in the ViewControllers where I want to restrict to only portrait.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

Still, when I press (Command + right or left arrow), the simulator rotates. I don't have a device, so I have to test it in simulator.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Are those methods getting called (set a breakpoint to check)? If you are using a navigation controller then they will only be getting called on the navigation controller.

Comment: I am using a navigation controller. But they are getting called. I did put println() statements to ensure that they're getting called.

Answer (score 0):

It's the parent navigation controller that decide if its content should rotate or note.

You will need to override UINavigationController and had something like this

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotae()
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotae()
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much @SeNeO ! It's working. But now there's another problem. If the user presses the back button from a video player in landscape mode, the previous VC does not rotate to portrait. viewWillAppear() is getting called. But it's not rotating to portrait. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: I added the code in viewWillAppear() in its child view controller's willMoveToParentViewController(). It is working! Thank you @SeNeO

Comment: Glad that had helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check. First, check your info.plist file and make sure that you have portrait deleted for both iPhone and iPad. I was having the same issue and it was because I hadn't deleted the iPad "Portrait" options. See here:

[image]

Second, the below code can help. However, it may not work if you have a navigation controller.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: He cannot delete portrait from the info.plist, because his app supports portrait orientation.